# Mysterious Circular Dependency

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula in L18 in which I cannot seem to find the problem of a circular dependency. If I put the exact same formula in Q18, it works. Note in my formula that the query avoids column L:

```
query({$E$2:$K,$M$2:$P}
```

So, I thought I was able to put this formula within Column L without an issue.  Apparently not!  Can you help me figure this out?

```
=if($P18>=40,if(($P18-($O18))>40,
($O18),index(query({$E$2:$K,$M$2:$P},"select (Col11 -40) where Col1 = date 
'" & text($E18,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' and Col2 = timeofday 
'"&TEXT($F18,"hh:mm:ss")&"'  and Col3 = timeofday 
'"&TEXT($G18,"hh:mm:ss")&"'"),2)))
```

I'm sure it's more useful to see it in context, so here is the link to the [**spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ORNeprrvlcA2iGULqi1L8kxGSthmhCzTxGpidI2ioeM/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in anoter column: `P` "Mon-Sun Total Hours"

Change it's formula so it doesn't show error:

```
= iferror ( formula , "")
```

[Your sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gry2RO7KKhNzZWeP_MbWaGJpokwskvWkxrItUOArld4/edit?usp=sharing)